# Simple approach for storing time series data

Tags: database, postgresql, time-series, google-bigquery, nosql

I have about 1 billion events daily. I need to store these events in the database for last 30 days, so it's about 30 billion rows.

Let's say it is athletes database, each row has only 4 column (athlete name, athlete's discipline, athlete rank, date). I need to retrieve data only by athlete name and date. For example build a graph for the last 30 days for particular athlete.

1. Initially I was using Google Big Query, this is great tool, extremely cheap, with daily sharding out of the box and linear scalability but with few drawbacks. Querying 3 billions table takes about 5 seconds, too much for my case. When data is inserted it appears in the "Streaming buffer" and can't be query for some time (about 5-10 minutes )
2. Another approach use Postgres and store all the data in the one table with proper indexes. Also I can use daily sharding (create new table automatically at the beginning of the day) But I have concerns whether Postgres can handle billion rows. Also if I want to get historical data for last 30 days, I have to make 30 SELECT queries when sharding data in such way.

I don't want to bother with over-complicated solutions like Cassandra (have never tried it though). Also I don't think I will get any benefits from using column-oriented database, because I have only 4 columns.

Looking for something similar to Big Query but without mentioned drawbacks. I think data can be stored in one node.

Comment: You do not need 30 selects to query for the last 30 days. And if the queries will be always the 30 days you do not need partitioning anyway. The only advantage in this case would be to discard the earlier day with a simple `drop table`. I'm not sure you understand Postgresql's partitioning.

Comment: The best solution depends on the complete situation and exact requirements. Daily partitioning *may* be useful.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I meant 30 select queries when I create tables manually without partitioning. I need to query range from 1 to 30 days.

Comment: I realize it's a simplified example, but what's the cardinality of the columns? How many athletes are there in total, what is the collection frequency (number of 'rank' measurements per day/hour/second)? Is the value of 'rank' metric relatively static for each 'athlete' or does it change with every observation?

Comment: See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614956/which-db-manager-for-a-100go-table/44625466#44625466 - PostgreSQL is capable to process such a data but you will need really powerful hardware or master/slaves architecture - so nothing cheap... To get results quickly you will have to pre-aggregate data for existing reports. There is no magical way around...

Comment: @SergeiRodionov Rank is measured once a day, sometimes even less often, rank is the number from 1 to 200. At the beginning there are about 300k athletes, later there will be up to 2 millions athletes. Rank can be changed on every observation. There are about 8 million discipline. Each athlete can be ranked on multiple discipline, but usually no more then 400 discipline per athlete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data can be stored using only one node. Actually, 1 billion rows per day is not much. It's only about 32K writes/second. For comparison, [Akumuli](http://github.com/akumuli/Akumuli) can handle about 1.5 million inserts / second on m4.xlarge AWS instance with SSD (almost half of that with EBS volume with default settings but you can provision more IOPS). To store 30B data-points you will need less than 200GB of disk space (it depends on your data but it's safe to assume that the data-point will take less than 5 bytes on disk).

The data model is simple in your case. The series name would look like this:

```
athlet_rank name=<Name> discipline=<Discipline>
```

You will be able to query the data by name:

```
{
  "select": "athlete_rank",
  "range": { "from": "20170501T000000",
             "to": "20170530T000000" },
  "where": { "name": <Name> }
}
```

You shouldn't chose Akumuli if you have large cardinality (many unique series). It consumes about 12KB of RAM per series, e.g. to handle the database with 1 million series you will need a server with at least 16GB of RAM (the actual number depend on series size). This will be improved eventually but at the moment this is what we've got.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Akumuli so I'm a bit biased. But I'll be happy to get any feedback, good or bad.